# Is there a way to make a Sheets script wait until a sheet is finished loading on the local PC?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[Copy-pasted from the Google forums,](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/RUnX0TRUcxo/MzOftAecAQAJ) was told to move it here.

I have a sheet that is shared with many coworkers that is used as an event log; we log problems that happen throughout the day, and how we fixed them. Each event is a new row. We wanted to make a script to run on load that would take a user to the last entry that was made, as we don't want to page down through 1300+ entries.

I made a script that finds the last entry, and puts the cursor there via the function **setActiveSelection(var).**

The problem is, while the cursor moves the the right cell, the window does not, it stops about 15 cells above it. So if the most current entry is at row 1300, the cursor will be at A1300, but the window will be about one window height above it, with row 1285 in the center of the window. If I move the cursor using the arrow keys, the window jumps to focus on the cursor. I tried overriding the variable and going to much lower value rows (like 500 and below), and also tried going to a midway point first (or near-end point like row 1200), before going to the end, under the suspicion that the sheet just wasn't loading fast enough for the script. I found that the only way to make it focus on the cursor the first time the script runs is to put a 2 second 'wait' before the selection change using **Utilities.sleep(2000).** It would seem that the sheet has not finished loading yet by the time the move is commanded, so the window does not go down as far as it can.

I think that's a very clunky solution, as that two second delay changes depending on the spec of the PC viewing the sheet. Some coworkers are on older laptops; less RAM, spinning disk drives, etc, and it takes up to 5x longer just to load the sheet to the point that the script runs, let alone to when the sheet is ready for the cursor jump. Is there a function to check if a sheet has loaded completely, so that I can check against that instead of blind guessing how log it will take?

Comment: one idea to help is to hide rows that are "done" automatically. this way there will be few active rows when you open it.